# Apostrophe-cms cloning a pieces area into another non pieces area

Tags: apostrophe-cms, apostrophe

I have an apos pieces collection called templates and in that schema I have an apos area for other widgets, etc.

I have created a standard non-pieces widget with a joinbyone that can pick the area but I can't seem to find a way to clone the items in the pieces area into the non pieces area in the widget.

The idea being I can create templates as pieces and when they are selected I create a copy of that template into an anonymous area so the pieces-area is unchanged. Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Widgets don't have their own `afterSave` type [event handler](https://docs.apostrophecms.org/advanced-topics/promise-events/promise-events.html#apostrophe-docs-aftersave-req-doc-options) because it's not really them that are saved. It's the document that they belong to. You could use the `afterSave` event handler on the doc type to:

1. See if the saved document include that widget in an area
2. See if the template widget has a populated join
3. Copy the area data from the joined document to the widget area
4. Clear the widget's join field (so it can see if a new template was selected in the future)

Step 3b is really to update the `_id` properties of all the widgets in the copied areas. Area widgets have unique `_ids` for when they are moved or copied, so those should be newly generated for this new context. The `cuid` utility is useful for that.

This is an unusual case, but it's certainly interesting. I think that might work if you need to do it. And it keeps the data correct rather than doing data work in the template.

Comment: It is worth understanding the context in which this is being used - Templates are built to contain lots of things like widgets and other recursive templates. The ref links to those templates need to be in tact so a document can maintain a list of all the pieces-templates used in the building of that document (but it does not need those pieces anymore). So I wanted a system not unlike the new merge tags but mutable. The flow of my approach from a UX point of view works as intended - I think your suggestion would leave an empty area until the save kicks in which wouldn't be good UX.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't seem to get a handle on the data server side so I used a template helper to post the data back in, then copied the area from the piece and ran the items through a re-dot-path/docid routine. Works a treat so far!

template.html

```
 {% import "macros/widgets.html" as widget %}
{%if data.widget%}

{% set section=apos.sectionTemplate.copyme(data.widget) %}

{%endif%}

{{ widget.postWidget(section, 'newnsection') }}
```

widget.js

```
const apos = require("apostrophe");

module.exports = {
  extend: 'apostrophe-widgets',
  label: 'Section Template',
  alias: 'sectionTemplate',
  defer: true,
  addFields: [
    {
      name: '_nsection',
      type: 'joinByOne',
      withType: 'templateSections',
      label: 'Template',
      required: true,
      idField: 'id',
      filters: {
        projection: {
          title: 1,
          nsection: 1
        }
      }
    }
    ,
    {
      name: 'newnsection',
      type: 'area',
      label: 'Section',
      contextual: true,
      def: ''
    }
  ],

  construct: function (self, options) {

    self.addHelpers({
      copyme: function (data) {
        if (data.newnsection.items.length == 0) {
          data.newnsection.items = data._nsection.nsection.items
          area = recalcDotPathsAreas(data.newnsection);

          function recalcDotPathsAreas(area) {
            var docId = area._docId;
            var dotPath = area._dotPath;
            area.items.forEach(stlevel);
            function stlevel(value, index, array) {
              var widgetDotPath = dotPath + '.items.' + index;
              try {
                var $widget = value;
                value.__docId = docId;
                value.__dotPath = widgetDotPath;
                recalcDotPathsAreasWidget(value, docId, widgetDotPath);
              } catch (e) {
              }
            };
            return area
          };

          function recalcDotPathsAreasWidget($widget, docId, dotPath) {
            $widget.items.forEach(sclevel);
            function sclevel(value, index, array) {
              var $area = value;
              var areaDocId = value._id;
              if ((areaDocId !== docId) && areaDocId && (areaDocId.substring(0, 1) === 'w')) {
                value._id = docId;
                areaDocId = docId;
              }
              if (areaDocId === docId) {
                var areaDotPath = value._dotPath;
                if (areaDotPath) {
                  var components = areaDotPath.split('.');
                  var name = components.pop();
                  value._dotPath = dotPath + '.' + name;
                  recalculateDotPathsInArea(value);
                }
              }
            };
          };
        }
        return data;
      }
    });

    var superPushAssets = self.pushAssets
    self.pushAssets = function () {
      superPushAssets()
      //  self.pushAsset('stylesheet', 'smart-section', {when: 'always'})
      self.pushAsset('script', 'always', { when: 'always' })
    }

  }

}
```